# Why (thisIsInTheArray in array) returns false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var codeList = [ "ok", "error" ]
var msg = { "status": "ok" }
console.log(msg.status in codeList) // returns false
```

It seems to be working on my iPad but not my computer. Here's a screenshot on my Chrome 64.0.3282.119, Windows 10 x64, JavaScript V8 6.4.388.40:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [The `in` operator does not do what you think it does.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: @Pointy So i can use `{ ok: "", error: "" }` and then use `in`?

Comment: The `in` operator tests if an object has a property defined. For example, `"0" in codeList` would be `true`.

Comment: thanks everybody btw sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

> The in operator returns true if the specified **property** is in the
>   specified **object** or its prototype chain.

Use [array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead.

PS: There are a lot of interesting stuff in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) ;)

Comment: As I understand the question he just need to check if status is one of the allowed statuses, so `codeList.includes(msg.status)` should do the work